# F# - Http request response body to string to use with json type provider

Tags: http, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I get a response from a web api which simply returns an F# record of the data corresponding to the id in the request url.

The question I have is how do I get the text representation of the response.Body so I can plug it into the commented out line below and use it with json type provider. Or is there a different way of doing this that I am missing,

```
let response = Http.Request("http://localhost:50442/api/getrates/" + input)

        let sample = Json.Sample.Parse(""" {"CurrencyId":1,"CurrencyCode":"AUD","Value":0.98542} """)
        //let sample = Json.Sample.Parse("\"\"\" " + response.Body.ToString() + " \"\"\"")

        let data = sample.Value

        return "Rate for: " + input + " = " + data.ToString()
```

Comment: JsonProvider offers Load(requestUrl), it should do what you want without extra Http.Request

Answer (score 4):

You need some sample JSON for the type provider to inspect at compile-time (from a local file, a literal string, or from a remote URL), which is used to detect the schema and generate the types.

Then at runtime you dynamically load some new data set which matches the same schema, and you have typed access.

```
// provide some URL, file path, or raw JSON sample
// that can be used at compile time to generate types
type Json = JsonProvider<"sample.json">


// at runtime, load up new sample matching that schema
let response = Http.Request("<some url that serves JSON at runtime>")
let samples = Json.Parse(response.Body.ToString())

// or do it this way
let samples = Json.Load("<some url that serves JSON at runtime>")

// magic!
sample.[0].EyeColor
```

Comment: Thanks @latkin for the answer sorted my problem. Just one thing for anyone else looking at this, is there is a slight syntax error on this line let samples = Json.Load("<some url that serves JSON at runtime>"), it should be Json.[type name].Load("<some url that serves JSON at runtime>")